# How can I fit a folder of images into one matrix in R?

Tags: r, image-processing

I have a folder of letter images. it contains 182 image, each image can be represented in a 12 by 12 matrix. I'm performing a fuzzy c means algorithm. I want to create a loop to fit all images into one matrix or create a loop to fit each image into one matrix. what is the most easy way to do it ?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If get_mat() is your function to convert image to matrix.
For fit each image in an individual matrix

```
## Set working directory to where images are located
setwd("folder location")

## List files
img_list <- list.files()

## Read files into a list of matrix
img_mat_list <- lapply(img_list,get_mat())

## To join all those matrix rowbind or columnbind
do.call(rbind,img_mat_list)
do.call(cbind,img_mat_list)
```

Comment: Thank you. Exactly what i'm looking for.

Comment: Accept the answer if it answers the question.